# A winner's attitude IS, says Lao Tzu, YOU... (sentence style)

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

In this statement:

> A winner's attitude **is**, says Lao Tzu, a philosopher, ''**you** have to know when to fight and when not to fight.''(I've made this up)

For me it sounds a bit weird to sepearate the ''is-you'' in this sentence. Do you find this as a weak, normal, or an advanced sentence construction?

Comment: Think of it as: A winner's attitude is ''you have to know when to fight and when not to fight.'' This is OK, but your example reads poorly due to the placement of "says Lao Tzu, a philosopher". I would put it at the end. Or possibly after *attitude*. Is there a source for this quotation?

Comment: You don't have the first part in quotes. I also don't recognize that exact quotation from anywhere. I haven't heard a Lao Tzu's phrase translated as "a winner's attitude" before.

Comment: @JasonBassford, oops I've made this one up.

Comment: There is a reduced '[that]' right after the 'is'.  The adverbial (with apposition) separates that pronoun from its antecedent, which is clumsy.

Comment: @amI, are you saying that there 'should' be **that** immediately after **is**?

Comment: @JohnArvin If you made it up, then it would sound better if it were: *Lao Tsu, a philosopher, said of a winner's attitude that "you have to know when to fight and when not to fight."* Although, if you made it up, I would remove the quotation marks altogether since it's not an actual quote: *Lao Tsu, a philosopher, said that a winner's attitude is knowing when to fight and when not to fight.*

Comment: @JohnArvin - putting 'that' right after 'is' won't help, but putting it right before "you... won't hurt (although the adverbial may still tempt the listener down a garden path).